# Graphite historical data merge

Tags: graphite, whisper

I have **Carbon Aggregator** and **whisper** in my **Graphite** setup, seems to be working well.

I have a situation where part of my data can be stale, and so it will be **replaced** (NOT aggregated) with the data already recorded for that historical period of time. How to handle that situation in Graphite if I want it to be **aggregated** (summed/averaged) not replaced.

It seems like if you have 1 hour of metric's aggregated value just committed to whisper and new data which just arrived, it spoils all the data for previous hour???

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure what you mean, but graphite now comes with a tool specifically for merging without overwriting newer data called [`whisper-fill`](https://github.com/graphite-project/whisper#whisper-fillpy).